# Update Custom Field daily within 7days

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

Is it possible to update the custom field daily within 7days?

**For Example:**

When a user created a new post, inside the post there's a Custom field name `Points Earned`. I would like to updated the `Points Earned` daily that will end within 7days based on the date they are created the post?

If a user have `10` Points then 24 hours later that points needs to increase by 10% and the automatic update will end in after 7 days.

I would like to know if that possible in cron? How?

Answer (score 0):

Using `wp_schedule_event()` function, you can create your custom function to do this. and how to use this function [refer this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_schedule_event/)